# PHP Warnings, is this normal?

Tags: php, warnings

I am having these warnings in my code despite that it works so was wondering if I am not writing these code properly or something.  Have a look.

```
$image_size = getimagesize($data[$module['_attr']['id']]); <-- works but gives warning (Filename cannot be empty)

echo call_user_func($module['_attr']['type'],$module); <-- works but gives warning (First argument is expected to be a valid callback)
```

So I am drawing to a conclusion that it doesn't like variables passed in or array elements.  Or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: It's extremely likely that `$data[$module['_attr']['id']` is empty. Have you done a test output?

Comment: When you say the `getimagesize` "works", what do you mean by this and how do you know? Sounds like it's empty, as the warning says.

Comment: both the functions work as in I will get a size array in $image_size and echo function does work as i can see it pulling data. No they are not empty 110% sure.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing `$data[$module['_attr']['id']]` is empty *(it doesn't contain a path to any file)* -- which would explain the first warning.

And `$module['_attr']['type']` probably doesn't contain a valid function name -- which would explain the second warning.

Try using something like this to know what's really in `$module` and `$data` :

```
var_dump($module, $data);
```

Notes :

- Those warnings indicate your code doesn't *work* : it doesn't do what you want it to do -- probabaly doesn't do much, considering the warnings.
- But warnings are not Fatal Error : the execution of the script continues ; even if there is some problem -- which could lead to troubles later.

Comment: call_user_func takes in a function name as string and that is exactly what I passed to it in the array element.

Comment: Well, the warning states what's passed to `call_user_func` is not a valid callback ; which means that, even if it's a string, it's the name of a valid function *(if it's the name of a function defined in another file, make sure that file is included, so the function is known by PHP)*

Comment: So it is possible that it gives warning that it is not a valid callback BUT it still works?  I am working with multiple php files and they are all included.  Basically the $data is big array containing data of the function names...So when i call "call_user_func", I am simply putting in the function name from the $data array element...Nothing crazy there...I could have easily substituted the array with the actual function name and it would also work and the warning is gone.  But because the code is running through a loop, the function name from $data is different thus i am passing in an array.

Comment: Are you **really sure** the function is actually really called ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your script is working?

I think the first error is because you aren't passing a image path to that function.

The 2nd, is because the first argument MUST be a function.
Is **$module['_attr']['type']** a function?

Are you debugging those variables?

Comment: yes everything works...The 2nd I am passing in a function name stored in the array so instead of saying call_user_function('name',$variable), I am substituting 'name' with the name inside the array element $module['_attr']['type']

Comment: Is that function, in the same script scope?

Comment: Not sure what you are referring to but take note that everything works even though their are warnings.